# How to solve the stale element reference exception in Selenium on clicking on button and verifying the title of next page?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, automated-tests

The below test is written using Selenium-

I have a test case where I click on a "next>>" button and the application performs some calculation on server and renders to a new page, but after clicking the "next>>" button sometimes it takes 1-2 minutes to open the next page.
In this test case I am verifying the title of next page to confirm that the next page actually opened and after that I perform further actions to this next page.

But the problem I am facing is when I click on "next>>" button and server take some time, the code to verify the title gives stale Element Reference Exception. If I remove the verify Title code block it perform further actions without any error.
Please suggest some solution to this problem.

Comment: Ca you share the code that you are using to verify title?

Comment: Yea sure, I am using the following code: Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Matrix Prices","The title for Matrix Price Management page is incorrect.");

Comment: Need to some selenium and html code..

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal Can you please share some of your code work here & update the relevant HTML DOM in the Question area?

Comment: That will be a bit tough, as the code is not very simple. There are many classes working together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help as you didn't share the whole code 
but you can make selenium wait until the page is loaded before assertion

Try below code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(// element in the page to be 
displayed after you press next);
```

By using this before the assertion  Selenium will not make the assertion until the page is  loaded